# A driver approaches a traffic light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, mathematical-physics

A driver approaches a traffic light, which is green with speed $ v_0 $ when it turns yellow.

a) If the driver's reaction occurs within temp $ T $, during which he decides to stop and apply the brake foot, and if the maximum brake deceleration is $ a $, what is the minimum distance $ S_ {min} $ before hitting Does the intersection, the moment the light turns yellow, can it make the car stop without crossing it?

b) If the yellow light stays on for a time $ t $ before turning red, what is the distance $ S_ {\max} $, before the intersection, the instant the yellow light comes on so that it can cross the intersection with speed $ v_0 $ without the red light coming on?

c) Show that in case the initial velocity is greater than$$ v_ {0\max} = 2a (t-T) $$there will be a range of distances before the rally so that the driver does not stop in time and cannot cross it without the red light coming on.

**Attemp:** a) We know that impulse is defined as
$$FT=m(v_2-v_1)$$. We also know that $v_2=0, v_1=v_0$ and $\sum F=ma$, so
$$maT=-mv_0\implies a=\frac{-v_0}{T}$$. Using the kinematic formula $d=v_0 t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ and plugging in our given equalities
$$d=v_0T+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-v_0}{T}\right)^2$$
b) I’m kind of confused about this... do we just plug in $T=t$ or do we do something like
$$d=\frac{d}{t}T+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d}{Tt}\right)^2$$

My biggest problem is c)

Comment: Do you have a conceptual question  about acceleration/velocity/position? "My biggest problem is c)" is not a well-formed question. It sounds like "please tell me how to do this," which is off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a) The car travels a distance $d_1=v_0T$ while the driver is reacting. It then travels a further distance $d_2=\frac{v_0^2}{2a}$ while decelerating at a rate $a$ before it comes to rest. So the total distance travelled is:

$S_{min}=d_1+d_2 = v_0T + \frac{v_0^2}{2a}$

b) This is simpler than you think. The car is travelling at a constant velocity $v_0$, so it will reach the intersection before the red light comes on as long as its distance from the intersection when the yellow light comes on (t seconds earlier)  is less than

$S_{max} = v_0t$

c) The driver can stop before the intersection if his initial distance is greater than $S_{min}$. And he can cross the intersection before the red light comes on if his initial distance is less than $S_{max}$. If $S_{min} \le S_{max}$ then for any initial distance he can either stop before the intersection or cross the intersection before the red light comes on (and for distances between $S_{min}$ and $S_{max}$ he can choose from both actions).

For what value of $v_0$ is $S_{min}$ equal to $S_{max}$ ? If $v_0$ is greater than this value then $S_{min} > S_{max}$. What happens now if the driver's initial distance is between $S_{min}$ and $S_{max}$ ?

Comment: I got all your tip! But how to prove it?

Comment: I still don't know how to prove it. I couldn't think of a distance left or missing to play in the equations

Comment: The initial distance can be whatever value you like. But if $S_{min} > S_{max}$ then there are distances which are less then $S_{min}$ - so the driver cannot stop before the intersection - and at the same time greater than $S_{max}$ - so the driver cannot cross the intersection before the light goes red. That is bad news for the driver.

Comment: Please don't answer these "do my work for me" type questions; they're off topic on this site and answering them only encourages more of these types of questions that we don't want.

Comment: @KyleKanos The OP has shown an attempted solution and explained where they are stuck, so that seems fine to me. The part of the question that requires thought is (c), where I have given hints, not a complete answer.

Comment: Showing an attempt is not sufficient; this is not a homework help site, period.

Comment: See, for instance, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12448/25301, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301, etc which all state that such questions are off topic and that giving such answers can lead to deletion of the post